# Why does Canada Post translate "to anyone" as "jusqu'à vous", not "à vous"?

Tags: traduction

Kindly see the picture below. Why doesn't Canada Post simply translate "to anyone" as "à vous"? Why use "jusque"?

[image]

A photo of a mail delivery truck from Canada Post shows a truck with the slogan « De partout... jusqu'à vous / From anywhere... to anyone » L'image d'un camion de courrier de  Postes Canada avec le slogan.

Comment: This isn't a translation. There's a French slogan and an English slogan, and they have similar constructions but not the same meaning. The 2001 [annual report](https://publications.gc.ca/site/fra/9.502711/publication.html) might shed more light on the choice of slogan, if there's more than what's cited in https://journals.openedition.org/eccs/291 . Unfortunately the 2001 report is too old to be online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) literal translation :

> **De n'importe où... à n'importe qui.**

would have been an extremely poor choice, as the meaning is more like "we do not care a lot of about who would actually get what was sent from whatever location".

***De partout*** means "from everywhere". This is positive. There are no places from where the mail won't be picked.

***À vous*** risks not to be immediately understood, because it can also mean "your turn" or "belongs to you", instead of highlighting the final destination/recipient.

***Jusqu'à vous*** (up to your place) is conveying the movement implied by the English "from - to":   Anywhere → transit → Anyone.

Comment: "Livrer n'importe quoi depuis n'importe où à n'importe qui!", un slogan qui aurait eu de la gueule!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Just to clarify, I never suggested or brought up "De n'importe où... à n'importe qui."

Comment: Indeed. As I wrote, this translation is from [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) which is usually not bad but here an example showing the current limits of machine translation.

Comment: @user52144 it's funny to realize that a valid translation could still be completely off because of the context.